# make VBA Search for entire row in excel

Tags: vba, excel

Dears Good Day[image: Main Picture]
in (main)picture i have these data and  in (exported)picture i have the result.
in my code i want to make (agent name) depends on specific row i will create it with agent names . that mean i don't want to duplicate the code for each agent .
if i add another agent it will automatically add another row in (exported)picture.in my code the row start with "A1" and for other records "A2","A3" and so on.....[image: exported Picture]
Simply I want make (Agent_Name) more than one record and depend on specific row i will create it

```
Sub MatchingCityAndCardType2()
Dim City As String, Sale_Type As String, Agent_name As String, i As Long, rData As Range, j As Long, Last_Row As Long
Last_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Remaining").Cells.ClearContents

For i = Last_Row To 2 Step -1
    Agent_name = Cells(i, "B").Value
    City = Cells(i, "D").Value
    Sale_Type = Cells(i, "E").Value

    If City = "Erbil" And Sale_Type = "bazar" And Agent_name = "Ali" And Mid(Cells(i, "H"), 1, 6) = 49000 Then
        'Set the range destination, Range(“A2”), depending on which
        'range you want in Sheets(“Remaining”)
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Remaining").Range("A1")
        Exit For
    End If

Next i



End Sub
```

Comment: Use the .find function, it's faster.

Comment: can you change my code with your function because i am beginner in vba

Answer (score 0):

I made Agent name a parameter.  The sub will now add rows that match the creteria to Sheets("Remaining").   You would call the sub like this `MatchingCityAndCardType2 "Ali"`

```
Sub MatchingCityAndCardType2(AgentName As String)
    Dim City As String, Sale_Type As String, Agent_name As String, i As Long, rData As Range, j As Long, Last_Row As Long
    Last_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Remaining").Cells.ClearContents

    For i = Last_Row To 2 Step -1
        Agent_name = Cells(i, "B").Value
        City = Cells(i, "D").Value
        Sale_Type = Cells(i, "E").Value

        If City = "Erbil" And Sale_Type = "bazar" And Agent_name = AgentName And Mid(Cells(i, "H"), 1, 6) = 49000 Then
            'Set the range destination, Range(“A2”), depending on which
            'range you want in Sheets(“Remaining”)
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Remaining").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Exit For
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to delete this line: `Sheets("Remaining").Cells.ClearContents` from your code. Second, you add this variable below the variable **Last_Row** :

`Last_Row2 = Worksheets("Remaining").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Third, replace the line:

```
Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Remaining").Range("A1")
```

with this line:

```
Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Remaining").Range("A" & Last_Row2)
```

Done!